# How append new Document in complicated Collection-Object

Tags: mongodb, database

I have a collection:

```json
{
    "_id": ObjectId("503b83dfad79cc8d26000004"),
    "uid": "9a8a2c5b9418cc1baadfa41255791414",
    "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "query": "lorem lorem",
        "list": [
          {
            "timestamp": "159",
            "provider": "Lor Em"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

Each collection element consist array of TASKS. Each TASK-element consist Query + List-array.

I must append if is possible new `TASK[index].LIST-object` (see diagram)

[image]

But I can not understand, how can I check all in `CASE_TO_FIND_ELEMENT`:

```json
db.myCollection.update(
    {<CASE_TO_FIND_ELEMENT>},
    {
        $push: {
            list: {
                timestamp: "1233",
                provider: "myNewProvier"
            }                
        }
    },
    {
        upsert: true,
        multi: false
    }
)
```

**Update:**
`newQuery -> any string` (for example from server) for using in `document.tasks[index].query`
This values i make in my code and must check if they exist in DB:
`uid + link + (query + (TIMESTAMP + PROVIDER))`

---

**Update v2**

```
> db.demo.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564f04f4be5d6f2f98c77dcd"),
    "uid" : "id3",
    "task" : [
            {
                    "list" : {
                            "lid" : "lX",
                            "ltext" : "demoX"
                    }
            }
    ]
}
```

Search `UID == "id3"` and in task-array  in list-array `"lid" == "lX"`, and if not found, push new doc in `task.list-array`:

```javascript
 db.demo.update({
     "uid": "id3",
     "task.list.lid": "lX"
 }, {
     $push: {
         "task": {
             "list": {
                 "lid": "lX2",
                 "ltext": "demoX2"
             }
         }
     }
 }, true, false)
```

But in this case mongo insert a new doc in array :(

```json
> db.demo.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("564f04f4be5d6f2f98c77dcd"),
        "uid" : "id3",
        "task" : [
                {
                        "list" : {
                                "lid" : "lX",
                                "ltext" : "demoX"
                        }
                },
                {
                        "list" : {
                                "lid" : "lX2",
                                "ltext" : "demoX2"
                        }
                },
                {
                        "list" : {
                                "lid" : "lX2",
                                "ltext" : "demoX2"
                        }
                }
        ]
}
```

---

Can you help me please to add some data in MongoDB collection?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you elaborate what `newQuery + etc` is?

Comment: @chridam : I updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Guessing what you want.

This is the original document

```
{"_id": ObjectId("503b83dfad79cc8d26000004"),
"uid": "9a8a2c5b9418cc1baadfa41255791414",
"link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions",
"tasks": [
  {
    "query": "lorem lorem",
    "list": [
      {
        "timestamp": "159",
        "provider": "Lor Em"
      }
    ]
  }
]}
```

you can do this:

```
db.demo.update({"tasks": { $elemMatch: { "query": "lorem lorem" }}}, {$push: {"tasks.$.list": {"timestamp": "160", "provider": "Lor Em"}}});
```

And you will have this in your updated document:

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("588b8ff15a66b2e3316ce70a"),
"uid" : "9a8a2c5b9418cc1baadfa41255791414",
"link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/questions",
"tasks" : [
    {
        "query" : "lorem lorem",
        "list" : [
            {
                "timestamp" : "159",
                "provider" : "Lor Em"
            },
            {
                "timestamp" : "160",
                "provider" : "Lor Em"
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/). That will only append to the array if it doesn't already exist. For example:

**Before update:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564f04f4be5d6f2f98c77dcd"),
    "uid" : "id3",
    "task" : [
            {
                    "list" : {
                            "lid" : "lX",
                            "ltext" : "demoX"
                    }
            }
    ]
}
```

**Then do the update:**

```
db.demo.update({
     "uid": "id3",
     "task.list.lid": "lX"
 }, {
     $addToSet: {
         "task": {
             "list": {
                 "lid": "lX2",
                 "ltext": "demoX2"
             }
         }
     }
 }, true, false)
```

**After first update:**

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("564f04f4be5d6f2f98c77dcd"),
        "uid" : "id3",
        "task" : [
                {
                        "list" : {
                                "lid" : "lX",
                                "ltext" : "demoX"
                        }
                },
                {
                        "list" : {
                                "lid" : "lX2",
                                "ltext" : "demoX2"
                        }
                }
        ]
}
```

**After second update:**

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("564f04f4be5d6f2f98c77dcd"),
        "uid" : "id3",
        "task" : [
                {
                        "list" : {
                                "lid" : "lX",
                                "ltext" : "demoX"
                        }
                },
                {
                        "list" : {
                                "lid" : "lX2",
                                "ltext" : "demoX2"
                        }
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But "list" in my case is an array. Is it possible to update without 2 ways check?

Comment: @ElderovAli In your question `list` is not an array. I'm not clear on what you are asking

Comment: In my question: list is array, see on top side. All what I have in Update-section is maximum what i can do without creating list as array. :(